# Gradle dynamic dependencies

Tags: groovy, gradle

```
4.times{ number -> 
   task "task$number" << {
      println("task$number");
   }
}

task2.dependsOn task1, task0, task3
```

The code above set the task `task2` depends on any other task defined here. But what is `task2.dependsOn` in the groovy syntax? It doesn't look like method invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a method invocation taking 3 parameters

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Statements

> **Optional parenthesis**
>
> Method calls in Groovy can omit the parenthesis if there is at least one parameter and there is no ambiguity.
>
> ```
> println "Hello world"
> System.out.println "Nice cheese Gromit!"
> ```